# efficientnetb0 error while loading pretrain weights

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to load pretrain weights for EfficientNetB0. Because of Firefall issue, I downloaded the h5 file and gave that path. I get an error saying, `You are trying to load a weight file containing 130 layers into a model with 131 layers`

My code is:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import EfficientNetB0
basemodel = EfficientNetB0(weights=r"C:\path\filename.h5", include_top=False, input_tensor=Input(shape=(224,224,3)))
```

Keras version is 2.6.0

I downloaded weights from this link:
https://www.kaggle.com/chopinforest1986/efficientnetb0b7-keras-weights?select=efficientnet-b0_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_autoaugment_notop.h5

Comment: Do you get the same error when setting `include_top=True`? That might be the reason.

Comment: when i change include_top to True , then i am getting the error like "You are trying to load a weight file containing 130 layers into a model with 132 layers"

Comment: Can you share the link to download weights, so that we can try it on our local machine?